# How to slide my sticky navigation to top negative?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation on the top of my page. The position should be sticky. Now when I scroll down, it should slideup and slide down. But when I scroll it to the top, it doesn't slideup anymore.

Can anyone help or share an alternative?

```js
var scroll = false;
console.log("ready!");
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && !scroll) {
        $('#nav').animate({"top": "-100px"}, 500);
        $('#nav').css({"background-color": "grey"});
        $('#nav').animate({"top": "0"}, 500);
        scroll = true;
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 100 && scroll) {
        $('#nav').animate({"top": "-100px"}, 500);
        $('#nav').css({"background-color": "rgba(120,112,125,.7)"});
        $('#nav').animate({"top": "0"}, 500);
        scroll = false;
    }
});
```

```css
#nav {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(120,112,125,.7);
    height: 95px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav" style="top: 0px;"></div>
<div style="height: 200vh;"></div>
```

Comment: It's because you animate to `top: -100px` then *immediately* animate back to `top: 0`. Don't do that. Also, the logic on both sides of your `if` statement do that same thing, bar the background colour.

Comment: how can I move the whole navigation out of the page and then back? @RoryMcCrossan